# convert jsonelement to json array in a json object from xml using org.json

Tags: json, org.json

I am using org.json to convert an xml to json using below code snippet.Unfotunately, there is a structure called "countries" which is supposed to be an array, but can have only 1 country sometimes. In such cases, array is not getting disaplyed instead "countries" is showing up under {} instead of [{}] or [].

```
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xsltresponse);
        return xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
```

output i am getting is with after json conversion is:

```
         {
          "data":{
              "name":"Microsoft",
               "date":"today",
                "countries":{
                      "name:"AN"
                         }}}
```

Instead of getting below output

```
             {
            "data":{
              "name":"Microsoft",
               "date":"today",
                "countries":[{
                      "name:"AN"
                         }]
                         }}
```

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to arrive at solution, this works fine. I will mark it as accepted answer. Please let me know other wise.

```
   JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(response);
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
  JSONObject data = xmlJSONObj.getJSONObject("data");
  JSONObject objArr = data.optJSONObject("countries");
  if (objArr != null) {
    jsonArray.put(objArr);
    data.putOpt("countries", jsonArray);
       }
```